# Best way to structure table for commission reports

Tags: sql, database-design

I want to have a table that will track all the commissions we are due from our wireless sales.  Each plan pays a different Commission, not a problem. We do our reconciliation as sometimes the carriers don't pay (they may miss a line or 2).

The problem occurs when the carriers change how much they pay for the commissions.  We want to be able to go back and see that there was 4 lines not paid for in January at commission rate x.  but Feb the same types of plans were sold but their commission rates were x-10.

If I change the rate in the commission table for the plan, when i go back to pull the data from the January report I will get incorrect commission rates.

I have a table for sales set up with a date stamp so I was thinking i can cross reference that somehow.

Hope someone followed this.

I am looking for the best way to structure this.

Answer (score 0):

You should "STAMP" the record with the commission rate.  You could either stamp the actual rate into every record... or you could keep a commission ID and put that into each record.

Comment: I know this makes your data not "normalized" but otherwise like you said you lose the data.